# Is it possible to check if an Angular app already has running app modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writting an Angular plugin that will initialize an angular app module if there are none found, but if there is an already running or declared ng-app, my app will use that module instead. Ideally my code would look like the following:

```
// return array of apps, whether from ng-app or manually bootstrap
runningAppModules = angular.getNgApps();

if( !isEmpty(runningAppModules) )
{
    var app = runningAppModules[0];
    // Do something with the already initialized app like register controllers
    // Or add directives
}
else
{
    // manually bootstrap apps
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  try {
    angular.module('module-name-here');
  } 
  catch(e) {
    //not loaded
  }
```

The `module()` function will throw an error if you call it for a module that doesn't exist, unless of course you're creating one with `angular.module('some-name', []);`. So, you can just wrap it in a `try/catch` block to check whether or not a module is loaded.

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/eYOluCEg/2/edit)**

```
var appElems = document.querySelectorAll('[ng-app]');

for (var i=0; i<appElems.length; ++i) {
  var appName = appElems[i].getAttribute('ng-app');
  try {
    angular.module(appName);
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log('Module "'+appName+'" not loaded!');
    //create the app
    angular.module(appName, []);
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I won't know what the module name will be ahead of time since the user can do something like: <body ng-app="some_weird_name">. My plugin will load angularjs if it is not present or manually bootstrap an app if there are no user defined apps. My plugin is meant to be used by angular/ non-angularjs users alike.

Comment: @Mr.Student is there anything wrong with searching the dom: `document.querySelectorAll('[ng-app]')` and using those values in the try/catch?

Comment: Not at all. I did not know about the querySelectorAll() option. You should include that in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Student Updated with live demo as well.

Comment: Technically this isn't checking if the module has been bootstrapped, only that it has been loaded. If your app is bootstrapped automatically using `ng-app` then you won't notice a difference, but if you're bootstrapping manually at some point later then you'll need to do something a bit fancier.